# Метод replace не изменяет строку

Tags: python, python-3.x, текст, replace

Есть код:

```
def abbreviate(s):   
    t = s[:]
    q = s.replace('-',' ').split()
    for i in q:
        r = i[0]+str(len(i[1:-2])+1)+i[-1]
        t.replace(i,r)
    return t
print(abbreviate("elephant-ride colinu"))
```

В котором метод replace(в коде: `t.replace(i,r)`) не выполняется (визуально), хотя по описанию метода должен.

Результат должен быть таким:

```
e6t-r2e C4u.
```

У меня выходит просто копия: `elephant-ride colinu`. Не могу понять, почему.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так вроде строки иммутабельны: [`string.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace).

Нужно:

```
t = t.replace(i,r)
```

Comment: Строки не изменяемые, `replace()` возвращает изменённую копию строки а не меняет старую.

Comment: @ПавелДурманов я вроде именно так и написал. Не? )

Comment: Я немножко дополнил, в целом все верно :)

Answer (score 2):

Строки неизменяемые, поэтому методы, что меняют их должны вернуть новые строки

А так, я бы попробовал алгоритм сделать через регулярные выражения

Пример:

```
import re


def abbreviate(s: str) -> str:
    def _on_match(match):
        word = match.group()
        return word[0] + str(len(word[1: -1])) + word[-1]

    return re.sub(r'\w+', _on_match, s)


text = 'elephant-ride colinu'
print(abbreviate(text))
# e6t-r2e c4u
```

Так как Regex является сокращением для кодирования, введем некоторые пояснения для регулярного выражения `r'\w+'`:

**\w**  - любая цифра или буква;
**+**   - 1 и более вхождений шаблона слева;

То есть, взять последовательность из цифр и(или) букв 1 и более длинны. Следовательно получим слово ограниченное пробелами.