# Замена строки в Python

Tags: python

Почему не работает метод replace()

```
string = 'Python is interesting'
print (string)
string.replace ('C','Python')
print (string)
```

Это не работает. Выводит:

```
Python is interesting
Python is interesting
>>>
```

Заранее спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Во первых вы пытаетесь заменить C на Python - символа С нет, а во вторых нужно создавать новую строку и присваивать её значение замены. (в 3й строке поменять string на новую строку)

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Теперь работает!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса [Метод replace не изменяет строку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/872893)

Comment: простите. Не видел

Comment: но это и не дубликат

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
str = string.replace ('Python', 'C')
print (str)
```

так будет работать!